# Laravel Eloquent save method throws Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've never had a problem with eloquent saving models, but today this model instance isn't working as well. It just throws me this exception.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /mnt/c/Desarrollo/displadu/displadu/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php
>   on line 743

This is the eloquent model instance

```
App\Paciente Object (
    [table:protected] => paciente
    [connection:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [NOMBRE] => 
            [APELLIDOS] => 
            [B3_TIPO_AV] => 4
            [STATUS_BASAL_pacIdCaso] => 1
            [pac_id_ext] => 5b4f24470b2a5
            [owner_id] => 2
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array()

    [relations:protected] => Array()

    [touches:protected] => Array()

    [timestamps] => 1
    [hidden:protected] => Array()

    [visible:protected] => Array()

    [fillable:protected] => Array()

    [guarded:protected] => Array(
            [0] => *
        )
)
```

Action method at controller, it just calls 3 methods, these methods can be reimplemented by inherited controllers.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $params = $this->storeVarsInizialization($request);
        $params = $this->storeValidateVars($request, $params); // common implementation
        return $this->storeVars($request, $params);
    }
```

StoreVarsInizialization just start the needed variables to gather all needed info.

```
public function storeVarsInizialization(Request $request) {
        return array(
            'subject' => Session::get('paciente'),
            'warnings' => array(),
            'warningsChecked' => true
        );
    }
```

storeValidateVars does all validation process using laravel validator and calling customValRules from child controller but don't do any assignment, just store warning, warningchecked and give validator results.

Controller method, this method is just part of a template pattern, executed from store action method, which just execute 3 specialized methods, to run the dynamic vars from form

```
public function storeVars(Request $request, $params) {
        $paciente = $params['subject'];
        $warnings = $params['warnings'];
        $warningsChecked = $params['warningsChecked'];
        $validator = $params['validator'];
        $completed = $params['completed'];
        $user = Auth::user();

        log_objectclass(Paciente::class);
        log_objectid($paciente->id);

        //Hide warning when patient is created
        if(isset($paciente->STATUS_BASAL_pacAlta)){ // Se ha guardado info en Alta
            // Default:: Show warning
            //Do nothing
        } else {
            // Search and remove warning :: Ingreso hospitalario
            unset($warnings['IC6_PACINCL_V0']);
        }

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            log_result(Log::RESULT_FAIL);

            return redirect('paciente/'.$this->formName.'/'.$paciente->id)
                ->withErrors($validator, 'formulario')
                ->withInput()
                //->with('warnings', $warnings)
                ->with('reload', 'reload');

        } else {
            if(!empty($warnings) && !$warningsChecked) {
                log_result(Log::RESULT_FAIL);

                return redirect('paciente/'.$this->formName.'/'.$paciente->id)
                    ->withErrors($validator, 'formulario')
                    ->withInput()
                    ->with('warnings', $warnings)
                    ->with('reload', 'reload');
            }


            $attr_obj = 'STATUS_BASAL_'.trim($this->formName);

            if($completed) {
                $paciente->$attr_obj = CODE_STATE_SUCCESS;
            } else {
                $paciente->$attr_obj = CODE_STATE_PROCESS;
            }

            unset($paciente->completed);


            try {
                DB::beginTransaction();
                log_result(Log::RESULT_OK);

                if($paciente->id > 0){

                    if (! $user->can('savePaciente', $paciente)) {
                        log_result(Log::RESULT_DENEGATED);
                        Session::flash('warning', '<strong>No tienes permisos suficientes para editar este paciente</strong>. Si el error persiste, contacta con el administrador del sistema.');
                        return redirect('app');
                    }


                    if (isset( $paciente->pac_id_ext)) {
                        // Update
                        updatePacientInPacientBD($paciente->NOMBRE, $paciente->APELLIDOS, $paciente->pac_id_ext );
                    } else {
                        $pac_id = createPacientInPacientBD($paciente->NOMBRE ,$paciente->APELLIDOS);
                        $paciente->pac_id_ext = $pac_id;
                    }

                    $paciente->NOMBRE  = '';
                    $paciente->APELLIDOS = '';


                    $paciente->update();
                    $this->postStore($request, false, $params);
                }else{

                    // Create patient on isolated BD
                    $pac_id = createPacientInPacientBD($paciente->NOMBRE ,$paciente->APELLIDOS);

                    $paciente->NOMBRE  = '';
                    $paciente->APELLIDOS = '';

                    if (!isset($pac_id)) {
                        throw new Exception('No se ha podido crear el paciente en BD externa');
                        back();
                    }

                    $paciente->pac_id_ext = $pac_id;

                    $paciente->owner_id = $user->id;

                    $paciente->save();
                    $this->postStore($request, true, $params);
                }
                DB::commit();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                DB::rollback();
                log_result(Log::RESULT_FAIL);
                throw $e;
            }



            if($request->ajax()){
              return response()->json(["valid"=>true], 200);
            }else{
              return redirect('paciente/'.$this->formName.'/'.$paciente->id)
                ->with('message', 'Formulario enviado correctamente');
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are saving this model

Comment: I've editted the original post, adding the controller code, as you can see near the end i just do $paciente->save() trusting in the awesomes of eloquent.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it's solved. The fail is because for some reason my model has that attribute, called "attributes".... it shouldn't be there... but just unseting it works fine everything.